# Refactor SQL Query , using CTE vs SubQuery

Tags: sql, refactoring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a dataset from an S3 Bucket, and currently I am trying to improve the performance of the query as the current two approaches I have work but I would like to see a better query and learn how to improve my sql skills. Sorry for no sample dataset to work with as I have not figured out a practical way to provide mock data when pulling from .json files in S3.

QUERY # 1

```
 WITH block_1 AS
    (
    SELECT 
    VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
    VALUE:COL2 AS COL2, 
    VALUE:COL3 AS COL3,
    VALUE:COL4 AS COL4
    from '@S3_BUCKET/', 
     lateral flatten( input => $1:value)), block_2 as 

(
SELECT 
VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
max(VALUE:COL4) AS MaxCOL4
from '@S3_BUCKET/', 
lateral flatten( input => $1:value)
group by COL1
 )

select b.COL1 as COL1B, b.COLB as COL1B, 
 a.COL3, a.COL4 from block_1 as A
join block_2 b 
on a.COL1 = b.COL1  and a.COL4 = b.MaxCOL4
 ;
```

QUERY #2 , I felt was an improvement, especially because you do not need to specify the column you want in the final `SELECT` statement (as I did above)

```
select a.* from 
(
SELECT 
VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
VALUE:COL2 AS COL2, 
VALUE:COL3 AS COL3,
VALUE:COL4 AS COL4
from '@S3_BUCKET/', 
lateral flatten( input => $1:value))a 
join 
(
select COL1, MAX(COL4) COL4
from 
(
SELECT 
VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
VALUE:COL2 AS COL2, 
VALUE:COL3 AS COL3,
VALUE:COL4 AS COL4
from '@S3_BUCKET/', 
 lateral flatten( input => $1:value))
group by COL1) b
on a.COL1 = b.COL1 and a.COL4 = b.Col4;
```

**The two above are my current attempt, wondering if there would be a way to make this query better?** The other route I was thinking was possibly using "where in" , and the list of COL1, but essentially then I still have to hit s3 2x , as the queries above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`window functions`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html), specifically [`RANK()`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/rank.html) to simplify this query:

```
WITH block_1 AS (
    SELECT 
    VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
    VALUE:COL2 AS COL2, 
    VALUE:COL3 AS COL3,
    VALUE:COL4 AS COL4,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE:COL1 ORDER BY VALUE:COL4 DESC) AS rk
    FROM '@S3_BUCKET/', 
     lateral flatten( input => $1:value)
)
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM block_1
WHERE rk = 1
```

This can be simplified thanks to Snowflake's `QUALIFY` clause, which allows you to use an alias for a window function in what is effectively a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
    VALUE:COL1 AS COL1, 
    VALUE:COL2 AS COL2, 
    VALUE:COL3 AS COL3,
    VALUE:COL4 AS COL4,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE:COL1 ORDER BY VALUE:COL4 DESC) AS rk
FROM '@S3_BUCKET/', 
     lateral flatten( input => $1:value)
QUALIFY rk = 1
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your time and response. I think the above is awesome but my plan is to scale this across many buckets, some of which I will have 100+ columns derived so having to select each column does not seem to quite be the fit because I will have to type them all out again after the select  statement, that is why I created my second query to circumvent that  @Nick

Comment: @0004 just change the `SELECT COL1, COL2...` to `SELECT *` and ignore the `rk` column?

Comment: this is a valid point and I thank you. I guess as well, I would appreciate a query that would be better than my last attempt , but designed using a "Where" or a better use of Join, or  simpler solution  than window - due to I have little experience using Window Functions and while I will read the link to the documentation(ty!) I want to be realistic about how I sequence my learning, and feel it may be better to see my second query tweaked or improved by a few notches vs jump to your query which may be at the master level (i think)? If this is to much to ask , no worries and thank you !! @Nick

Comment: @0004 in terms of not using window functions, I don't think you'll be able to significantly improve on your existing  queries as that is the standard way of achieving the result you want (search for greatest n per group on mysql) and you'll see lots of similar queries.

Comment: will do. Thank you for your help and feedback!

Comment: with the above it returns RK as a column though, so in order to get all the columns less the RK column you would have to select them then?

Comment: @0004 unfortunately yes. Is it not possible to ignore the `RK` column in your application?

Comment: did you ever see my response to use qualify. Just wanted to share my knowledge to help us all

Comment: @0004 No I didn't see it - people who post answers don't get notified when other answers are posted. You are absolutely right about `QUALIFY` - I should have remembered it. However I don't think `ROW_NUMBER()` is appropriate in place of `RANK()` as it will not give the same result as setting equal to the `MAX(COL4)` since there might be more than one row with the same maximum value.

Comment: @0004 you could consider writing that up as a complete answer and you can always accept your own answer. In the meantime I've edited mine to show the use of `QUALIFY`

Answer (score 0):

@nick. Use qualify , this will act as where filter and set = 1. Also replace rank with row_number. Does that make sense ?